# Reading contents or getting size of the buffer written by ssl_write()

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I am sending a data to amazon developer server with ssl_write(). I want to access the buffer written by ssl_write() and get information. Is this possible ?

Comment: The question strikes me as weird because *you supply the data* to be written in the call. Just look at the data that is yours. Or do you mean something else (e.g., do you mean something particular with "get information")?

Comment: we can assume that; 

const char *chars = " TEST " ;
SSL_write(ssl, chars, strlen(chars));

I know that in such a use, the chars array is kept in a buffer to be written.

I want to get the size or contents of the kept buffer. I will take an action in case of any disconnection or accumulation. If I misunderstood something, I would appreciate it if you could correct it.

Comment: @tryingBetter "*I want to get the size or contents of the kept buffer*" - that buffer is not accessible, there is no way to get any information about it. "*I will take an action in case of any disconnection*" - you don't need access to the buffer to do that. "*or accumulation*" - of what, exactly? "*If I misunderstood something*" - very much so.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau the ssl_write() function is keep writing data to buffer when ethernet down. It does not return any value or error if the buffer is not full. I was wondering, is the callback function available? As far as I searched, I couldn't find a function that would work for me. I want to do something when internet connection goes down. But without using keep-alive.

Comment: @tryingBetter this is normal behavior for a socket. If it is closed *gracefully*, subsequent reads/writes fail immediately. If it is terminated *abnormally*, you have to wait a time for the OS to invalidate the connection. TCP is designed to survive outages, so timeouts are required. Either app-level timeouts, or TCP keepalive, etc. If you want to detect when Ethernet goes down, you need to ask the OS for that info. For instance, on Windows, you can use the [Network List Manager API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nla/portal) for that